# Gnome applet watching for thunderbird inbox mails

Tags: gnome, thunderbird, plugins

I'm looking for a gnome applet that periodically would watch for thunderbirds mail accounts.

Something similar to gmail firefox plugin. Did anyone notice this kind of applet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a gnome applet, but might help : http://www.nongnu.org/mailnotify/

Also, there are screenlets apps available, IIRC.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear, I want applet/whatever similar to import accounts from thunderbird profile

Comment: Sorry, I don't think such a thing exists. The closest you'll come is manually adding your accounts to mail-notification.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that mail-notification can come pretty close to what you want. It won't auto-import, but it can directly read the Thunderbird INBOX files. You just have to point it to the files.

Comment: That still means I need to have Thunderbird open, to recieve new mails. I guess there is even no API to thunderbird's credentials. Maybe I someday write such thing

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [AllTray](https://launchpad.net/alltray) and dock Thunderbird in your system tray, then let Thunderbird's built in notification take care of it.